# Conectar php con sqlserver através ip

Tags: php, sql-server

Me han pedido que realice una serie de consultas desde una web en `php` a un servidor remoto (en otro servidor diferente) donde hay un `sql server 2005` para ver e introducir nuevos registros desde la propia web.

Como siempre hago, fui informándome ya que estoy acostumbrado a trabajar en `MySQL`, bueno que he ido probando lo que iba viendo, tras instalarme el driver y cliente de `SQLServer`. Y bueno que simplemente estoy probando de realizar la simple conexión pero no hay manera.

Mi primera duda es si usando una `IP` hay que añadir también el nombre de la instancia, ya que he visto en algunos sitios que la ponen y en otros no.

```
$serverName = "1.2.3.4"; 
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"base", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"pass");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Me sale este error

> Conexión no se pudo establecer.
>   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBBpl.png) => 3 [code] => 3 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [3]. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [3]. ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBBpl.png) => Array ( [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE] => HYT00 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBBpl.png) => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBBpl.png) => 3 [code] => 3 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. ) )

Se ha mirado que estén los `named piped` activados, así como que se acepten conexiones remotas.

Os agradecería la ayuda porque estoy colapsado.

[edición] Añado imágen con la configuración del TCP/IP con los puertos.
[image: configuración del TCP/IP]

Answer (score 2):

Yo también uso `sqlsrv_connect` para conectar a una base de datos SQL Server remota. Los parámetros de conexión que tienes son correctos (no es necesario agregar el nombre de la instancia, basta con la IP).

Si el servidor acepta conexiones remotas, puede que lo esté haciendo a través de un puerto que no es el estándar (el estándar es 1433). Si es este el caso, tienes que agregar el puerto a la IP del servidor:

```
$serverName = "1.2.3.4, 1542"; // IP, puerto
```

Comment: Perdona he tenido trabajo y no pude mirar esto, finalmente lo he probado y me cambia un poco lo del error, pero me sigue sin dejarme conectar. Aunque por lo que he visto se suele poner un puerto estático y por lo que parece en este servidor esta como dinámico, no se si tiene algo que ver con el problema de conexión. Verás la configuración en la edición que he realizado en la pregunta.

Comment: El error dice que no encuentra el servidor. Ojo que las IP que salen en la captura son internas, no te sirven para conectar desde fuera. Te sugiero revisar la info que tiene Microsoft sobre el tema https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177440.aspx

Comment: Entonces actualmente con la ip 192.168.1.50 daría sólo servicio a la red local, pero para conectarme desde fuera habría que poner su ip, es eso, verdad? Lo que pasa que hace poco instalaron una vpn, no pense que esto podría afectar a la conexión pero ahora pensandolo bien seguro que sí, entonces sabrías en esa configuración como debería ser con el vpn?

Comment: Exacto. Las ips 192.168.x.x son locales. Debes conocer la IP pública (externa) del servidor de la base de datos y además conectar a la VPN (esto también podría darte el error que mencionabas antes). Aquí me vas a disculpar, no sé exactamente cómo funciona la configuración del servidor, pero eso es a rasgos generales. Yo tengo una situación parecida a la tuya: conecto a la VPN de la empresa y en mis php uso sqlsrv_connect() para conectar a la IP del SQL Server. Funciona perfecto.

Comment: Entiendo lo que mencionas de poner la IP pública pero mencionas que aparte hay que conectar a la VPN, pero esto como sería? Comentas que tienes una situación parecida al tener que conectar también a un VPN, me puedes explicar como lo haces en esa situación? gracias

Comment: La VPN protege el acceso a ciertos recursos evitando que queden expuestos públicamente. Aunque el servidor SQL tenga IP pública, si está "dentro" de la VPN, hay que conectar a esta para acceder al servidor. En mi empresa la VPN protege los servidores SQL y el servidor web QA. Debo conectar a VPN para poder "verlos" y, por ej, leer la base de datos usando SQL Manager. Lo único que está fuera de la VPN es el servidor web de producción (no es necesario conectar a VPN para acceder al sitio web). El servidor web sí puede leer/escribir en el de base de datos porque son parte de la misma red interna.

Comment: Entonces por lo que dices si el SQL Server esta dentro del VPN no podría conectarme através del php? la única forma sería sacarlo fuera del VPN

Comment: La IP del SQL **debe** ir entre los parámetros de tu PHP. Si el SQL Server está en un servidor remoto que está protegido por VPN, entonces además **debes** conectar a esa VPN, o si no tu PHP te dará el error "No se encuentra el servidor".

Comment: Bueno, gracias por tus respuestas que me van guiando, hace unas semanas me dijeron que tienen problemas con el VPN y que ya me avisarán cuando esté todo listo así que no se si no se me conectaba por eso o por otra cosa. Solo una duda mencionas que me tengo que conectar al VPN primero para que no se lance el error del php, pero esto con las herramientas adecuadas, no por código php?